# Integration of a function approximated by a nth order polynomial

Tags: polynomials, definite-integrals, simpsons-rule

I've been playing with Simpson's rule and a thing came up to my mind. The rectangular rule is a 0th order polynomial approximation of integration. The trapezoidal rule is 1st. Simpson's rule is 2nd. Then what about nth? I've been working on this issue more than 2 weeks and couldn't get the answer. How could I solve this?

What I did is below.

## approach 1

A nth order polynomial function passing $n+1$ points $(x_i, y_i) (0 \leq i\leq n)$ can be written by Lagrange polynomial as

$$ g(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{n} y_i \displaystyle \prod_{i=0 \atop i \neq j}^{n} \frac{x-x_i}{x_j - x_i}$$

So, if $y=f(x)$, $g(x)$ is a polynomial approximation of $f(x)$. So, the integration of $f(x)$ can be written as follow.

$$ \int_{x_0}^{x_n} f(x) dx \simeq \int_{x_0}^{x_n} g(x) dx = \int_{x_0}^{x_n} \sum_{j=0}^{n} f(x_i) \displaystyle \prod_{i=0 \atop i \neq j}^{n} \frac{x-x_i}{x_j - x_i} dx \\
= \sum_{j=0}^{n} f(x_i) \displaystyle \prod_{i=0 \atop i \neq j}^{n} (x_j - x_i)^{-1} \int_{x_0}^{x_n} \prod_{i=0 \atop i \neq j}^{n} (x-x_i) dx
$$

Here, we suppose $x_i = x_0 + hi$ where $h$ is constant, $z = \frac{x - x_0}{h}$ and $z_i = \frac{x_i - x_0}{h} = i$ and the equation can be simplified.

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n} f(x_i) \displaystyle \prod_{i=0 \atop i \neq j}^{n} (x_j - x_i)^{-1} \int_{x_0}^{x_n} \prod_{i=0 \atop i \neq j}^{n} (x-x_i) dx \\
=  \sum_{j=0}^{n} f(x_i) \displaystyle \prod_{i=0 \atop i \neq j}^{n} (j - i)^{-1} h \int_{0}^{n} \prod_{i=0 \atop i \neq j}^{n} (z-i) dz$$

$f(x_i)$ was left intact intentionally. Solving equation boils down to solving $\int_{0}^{n} \displaystyle \prod_{i=0 \atop i \neq j}^{n} (z-i) dz$ which is quite difficult.

$S(z, j) := \displaystyle \prod_{i=0 \atop i \neq j}^{n} (z-i)$ can be written as follows.

$$S(z, j) = \displaystyle \prod_{i=0 \atop i \neq j}^{n} (z-i)
= \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i z^i$$

$a_i$ is constant. Notice the upper value of $\sum$ is $n$ for the number of $z$s in $\prod$ is $(n - 0 + 1) - 1 = n$ because $i \neq j$.

It is trivial $S(z, j) = 0$ when $z = 0, 1, ... , n$ but $\neq j$. So the following is true.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i z^i = 0 \,(z = 0, 1, ... , n \cap z \neq j)$$

The integration can be calculated as below.

$$\int_{0}^{n} \displaystyle \prod_{i=0 \atop i \neq j}^{n} (z-i) dz = 
\int_{0}^{n} S(z, j) dz = \int_{0}^{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i z^i dz \\
= \big[\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i \frac{z^{i+1}}{i+1}\big]_{0}^{n} \\
= \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i \frac{n^{i+1}}{i+1}$$

To solve this, evaluating $a_i$ is required. $a_i$ can be evaluated as below.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i z^i = 0 \,(z = 0, 1, ... , n \cap z \neq j) \\
\Leftrightarrow
\displaystyle 
  {\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
    1 & 2 & 2^{2} & \cdots & 2^{n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    1 & n & n^{2} & \cdots & n^{n} 
  \end{pmatrix}}
{\begin{pmatrix}a_{0}\\a_{1}\\a_{2}\\\vdots \\a_{n}\end{pmatrix}}
= {\begin{pmatrix}b_{0}\\b_{1}\\b_{2}\\\vdots \\b_{n}\end{pmatrix}} \\
(b_i =   
\begin{cases}
  S(j,j)\,\,(i = j) \\
  0 \,\,(i \neq j)
\end{cases}
)
$$

As $a_n = 1$ and $a_0 = \prod_{i=0 \atop i \neq j}^{n} -i$ the equation can be written as follows.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i z^i = 0 \,(z = 0, 1, ... , n \cap z \neq j) \\
\Leftrightarrow
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i z^i = -z^n \,(z = 1, 2, ... , n \cap z \neq j) \\
\Leftrightarrow
\displaystyle 
  {\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
    1 & 2 & 2^{2} & \cdots & 2^{n-1} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    1 & n & n^{2} & \cdots & n^{n-1} 
  \end{pmatrix}}
{\begin{pmatrix}a_{1}\\a_{2}\\\vdots \\a_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}}
= {\begin{pmatrix}b_{1}\\b_{2}\\\vdots \\b_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}} \\
(b_i =   
\begin{cases}
  S(j,j) - z^j\,\,(i = j) \\
  -z^i \,\,(i \neq j)
\end{cases}
)
$$

The leftmost matrix is Vandermonde's matrix and multiplying its inverse matrix to the left of both sides gives $a_i$. However, the inverse matrix is quite complicated and I find it pretty hard to calculate ([Inverse of Vandermonde's matrix](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde%27s_Matrix)).

## approach 2

I guessed $i \neq j$ makes the problem difficult. So I went for deleting it.

$$ \int_{0}^{n} \displaystyle \prod_{i=0 \atop i \neq j}^{n} (z-i) dz =
\int_{0}^{n} \frac{\displaystyle \prod_{i=0}^{n} z-i}{z-j} dz$$

The limit of $\frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n} z-i}{z-j}$ when $z$ approaches $j$ is given by L'hospital's rule, which is finite.

$$ \frac{(\prod_{i=0}^{n} z-i)'}{(z-j)'}|_{z=j} = (\prod_{i=0}^{n} z-i)'|_{z=j}$$

But after hours of thinking, I couldn't come up with how to solve $\int_{0}^{n} \frac{\displaystyle \prod_{i=0}^{n} z-i}{z-j} dz$. Two $z$s at both the enumerator and denominator. Integration by parts didn't work.

I've read the following articles and still didn't make it to find the answer.

1. [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum)
2. [Newton–Cotes formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cotes_formulas)
3. [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)
4. [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)
5. [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature)

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

That is a very interesting question. If you're still interested here are some things you can look into.

The sequence for the n-th order is given in the OEIS, namely at [A002177](http://oeis.org/A002177), [A002178](http://oeis.org/A002178), [A002179](http://oeis.org/A002179), .... You are looking for the Cotesian numbers.
The whole triangle (this is probably the one you want, with the values calculated up to 100-th degree polynomials) is given at [A100642](http://oeis.org/A100642). I believe that that is what you are looking for.

In the above sequences there is a link to a scanned copy of W.M. Johnson's paper "[On Cotesian numbers: their history, computation and values to n=20](http://oeis.org/A002176/a002176.pdf)". This will provide you with some explanation on how to calculate them.

---

**Update (1 july 2022):** I conducted the full derivation of the closed form expression for the Cotesian numbers in my bachelor thesis "[Methods for reducing error in approximations of the Rayleigh integral](http://resolver.tudelft.nl/uuid:c48fa27f-d91b-4c07-a74b-6ac6762bc095)" in appendix B.

If we let $s(n, k)$ denote the signed Stirling numbers of the first kind, the closed form expression of the Cotesian numbers is proven to be
$$c_i = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \binom{n}{i} \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{m=0}^{n-j} i^m n^j \frac{(-1)^{i+n} s(n+1, j+m+1)}{j+1}\,.$$

---

**Update (4 october 2022):** The [specific pages](https://github.com/jorisperrenet/BachelorThesis/blob/main/lemmas/cotesian_numbers.pdf) of the derivation can now also be found on my [github](https://github.com/jorisperrenet/BachelorThesis) page.